# How to get git not to do any line ending conversions except for specific file types

Tags: git, newline, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

I would like git not to do any line ending conversions except for specific files (say `.c` and `.h`). I would like to do it through `.gitattributes` so I can override any environment on users' machines. This is primarily targeted at Windows clients.

I want something like this:

```
* -text

*.c eol=lf
*.h eol=lf
```

But git is just ignoring everything after the first line (it's performing no line end manipulation at all).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `* -text` line is explicitly declaring that all files should be handled as binary. This will supersede your EOL settings, as they only apply to text files. You can bypass this by forcing text mode on your whitelisted extensions.

```
* -text
*.c text eol=lf
*.h text eol=lf
```

GitHub has a good article on this, for more detail
https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

EDIT: re-read your post, and tailored the response to better match your requirements

Comment: That works. I missed the `text` bit. There are lots of different file types (50+) in the repo. Most of them should never be line adjusted. Is there a specific problem with `* -text`? Will `merge` or `diff` behave differently? All I want is no line ending modification except for a couple very specific file types.

Comment: @dbv I'm not certain, hence my original advice to avoid it. The Git documentation is bit weak on this IMO, as it doesn't really discuss all the nuances. There is a separate `-diff` flag that will definitely effect diffs and merges, but I think you are okay with just `-text`. You may want to read through the docs a bit. Or you could just try and see :) I didn't find much there, but you may be able to glean some info from the Git book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

Comment: Thanks. I'll look through the book. I think a test will provide a definitive answer (not that hard to test merge and diff).

Comment: If someone bumps into this: I did a test and `* -text` doesn't do anything bad to text files that aren't explicitly listed below